# In Makefile, run a dummy target (first) if other targets out of date (or run recipe before dependencies)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

(using GNU make)

I have a `Makefile` with default target being responsible for 'compiling' code.  I than have `run_test` target that executes tests but will recompile if required.

I want to clear a log file **before** any compilation steps are run, but **only if** compilation steps are run, so not if just a test runs.  I defined a `reset_log` target to clear the logs.  The behaviour I want is:

1. `make all` when all up to date - nothing runs, logs not cleared
2. `make all` when **not** up to date - logs cleared, then appropriate compile rules run
3. `make run_test` when all up to date - nothing compiles, logs not cleared, tests run
4. `make run_test` when **not** up to date - logs cleared, then appropriate compile rules run, then tests run

How do I get the `reset_log` target (or equivalent commands) to run only when compilation must occur, but before any dependency recipe runs?  Here is simplified `Makefile`:

```
LOG_FILE = file.log

all: compile

compile: final.out

reset_log:
    -rm -f $(LOG_FILE)

final.out: final.in reset_log 1.out 2.out
    cp -v final.in final.out | tee -a $(LOG_FILE)

1.out: 1.in
    cp -v 1.in 1.out | tee -a $(LOG_FILE)

2.out: 2.in
    cp -v 2.in 2.out | tee -a $(LOG_FILE)

run_test: compile
    @echo "======= Run Test Here ======="


clean:
    -rm *.out $(LOG_FILE)

.PHONY: local_target reset_log run_test clean
```

**NOTE:** this example **does not work** (`reset_log` and `final.out` targets get rerun every time, because `reset_log` is a dependency of `final.out` and in itself has no dependency), but demonstrates where I would want `reset_log` to be run.

One possible solution would be to have a way to run a recipe for a target out of date before the dependency recipes are run.

---

**Update 2016-10-18**

Based on user657267's solution (and the minor improvement I suggested in a comment), here is a re-code of above example, i.e. the final solution to what I need:

```
LOG = file.log

all: compile

compile: $(LOG)

$(LOG): final.out
    mv $@.tmp $@ || ( echo "WARNING: $< not found. Creating dummy $@ to allow make to run" > $@ )

final.out: 1.out 2.out

%.out: %.in
    cp -v $< $@ | tee -a $(LOG).tmp

run_test: compile
    @echo "======= Run Test Here ======="


clean:
    -rm *.out $(LOG)

.PHONY: run_test clean compile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a second temporary log file

```
log := file.log
out := final.out 1.out 2.out

.PHONY: run_test clean

$(log): $(out)
    mv $@.tmp $@

run_test: $(log)
    @echo "======= Run Test Here ======="

clean:
    $(RM) $(out) $(log)

%.out: %.in 
    cp -v $< $@ | tee -a $(log).tmp
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @user657267.  The only case where this fails is if file.log gets manually removed and all other dependencies are up to date.  I fixed that by using following log move comand: `mv $@.tmp $@ || ( echo "WARNING: $@.tmp not found. Creating dummy $@ to allow make to run" > $@ )`